# JavaScript: add AD security groups to list item permissions

Tags: javascript, permissions, ad

I use the code below to group permissions on list items. This works fine for SharePoint groups.

How'd I do this for AD security groups?

(SP2013)

```
restrictToGroup = function( a ) {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext( a.sSite );
    var web = ctx.get_web(); 
    var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle( a.sList );
    var oListItem = oList.getItemById( a.id );
    oListItem.breakRoleInheritance(false);
    for( sGroup in a.aGroups ) {
        var sAccess = ( a.aGroups[ sGroup ] == "rw" ) ?
            SP.RoleType.contributor :
            SP.RoleType.reader ;
        var oGroup = web.get_siteGroups().getByName( sGroup );
        var oAccess = web.get_roleDefinitions().getByType( sAccess );
        var oBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(ctx);
        oBinding.add(oAccess);
        oListItem.get_roleAssignments().add(oGroup,oBinding);
    }
    oListItem.update();
    ctx.load(oListItem);
    ctx.load(oGroup);
    ctx.load(oAccess);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(a){console.log(a);console.log('ok')},
        function(a){console.log(a);console.log('err')}
    );
}
restrictToGroup({
    sSite : '/sites/jr/',
    sList : 'SideBar',
    id : 1,
    aGroups : {
        'jr Members' : 'rw',
    'jr Visitors' : 'r'
    }
});
```

Comment: Never done it, should be possible to use the Azure API, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Danny, thanks for your reply, however, we run SP2013 on premise at the moment, that is, I can't leverage the Azure API at this point :/